# How can I implement user timezone & user's last login in this format?

Tags: 7

Im trying to create a block and I'm  having trouble. I'm trying to get the user's last login & the user's timezone. How can I implement those functions in these hooks. All I know is the fact that I need to use the functions of hook_info & hook_view.

```
function hook_block_info() {

  $blocks[‘syndicate’] = array(
    ‘info’ => t(‘Syndicate’),
    ‘cache’ => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  $blocks[‘recent’] = array(
    ‘info’ => t(‘Recent content’),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function hook_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {

  if (is_array($data[‘content’]) && asset($data[‘content’][‘#contextual_links’])) {
    unset($data[‘content’][‘#contextual_links’]);
  }

  if (is_array($data[‘content’]) && $block->module == ‘some module’) {
    $data[‘contentr’][‘#theme_wrappers’][] = ‘mymodule_special_block’;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global `$user` object to get user details, or load user details from a uid like this: `$user = user_load($uid);` From the `$user->login` property you can get last login timestamp.

Thanks